# Ray: multiprocessing differences (class vs functions)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ray

new to Ray here (running on Windows 10 / WSL2 / Python 3.8)

I'm spotting differences between running a remote method and a remote function.

The following case will spawn 4 workers but workload will only run on one of them (running at 250% CPU)

```py
import ray
import time

ray.init(num_cpus=4)

@ray.remote(num_cpus=4)
class ParallelSquare():
    def square(self,v):
        return v*v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ps = ParallelSquare.remote()
    futures = [ ps.square.remote(i) for i in range(1,100000) ]
    l = ray.get(futures)
    print(l)
```

[image]

Whereas this second example will evenly distribute load between all workers (~75% each):

```py
import ray
import time

ray.init(num_cpus=4)

@ray.remote
def square(v):
    return v*v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    futures = [ square.remote(i) for i in range(1,100000) ]
    l = ray.get(futures)
    print(l)
```

[image]

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Actor vs task. actors only exist in a single process, while tasks get distributed. Generally you would have many actors so they could work in parallel.

Comment: [here's](https://towardsdatascience.com/modern-parallel-and-distributed-python-a-quick-tutorial-on-ray-99f8d70369b8) a great introduction to ray. Specifically take a look at the "From Classes to Actors" section.